# Fix wrong auto imports in TypeScript monorepo

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript mono repository with the following basic file layout:

```
├── packages/
│   ├── workspace-a/
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── workspace-b/
│       ├── src/
│       └── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

The root `tsconfig.json` looks like this (with irrelevant properties stripped):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@scope/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    },
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json` for each package looks like this:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig"
}
```

All packages use the `@scope` scope. This setup makes the following code work from `workspace-a`, as expected:

```js
import { Foo } from '@scope/workspace-b';
```

However, the following code works too according to `tsc` and is suggested by auto imports in VSCode first:

```js
import { Foo } from '@scope/workspace-b/src';
import { Bar } from 'packages/workspace-b/src';
```

The latter doesn’t work once packages are published to npm, causing issues **after** the packages have been published.

Can I make TypeScript disallow the latter? I’ll accept a solution involving an existing ESLint rule as well.

The full source code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/appsemble/appsemble).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is caused by the `baseUrl` option. This was previously needed when using the `paths` option.

As of TypeScript 4.1 [`paths` can be used without `baseUrl`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#paths-without-baseurl).

So the `tsconfig.json` would look like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@scope/*": ["./packages/*/src"]
    },
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Omitting the `baseUrl` is [not yet supported](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths/issues/143) by `tsconfig-paths`, which is also used by various popular TypeScript related packages, such as:

- [`eslint-import-resolver-typescript`](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/eslint-import-resolver-typescript)
- [`eslint-plugin-import`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import)
- [`tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin/issues)

Note that if you use `tsconfig-paths` for `"paths"` to work with `ts-node`, [you must explicitly specify `"baseUrl"` with it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths#user-content-bootstrapping-with-explicit-params) because it [does not yet support unspecified baseUrl](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths/issues/143).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! Before it was auto-importing from `packages/ui` but now imports correctly from `ui`.