# Fix auto-imports in TypeScript monorepo

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, monorepo, auto-import

I am trying to set up a monorepo as I thought sharing common code is a great idea in an ecosystem of applications as they have a lot of common types, logic and functions. My repo includes a React Native app, a React app, a Next app, and an Express backend application as well.

I am using Yarn workspaces. And I have added `shared-types` as a dependency in the React Native and React apps. The auto imports work fine in the React app but not in the React Native. When I manually add the import everything works fine, but the auto imports just wouldn't work.

I have done some digging but couldn't find anything useful. The things that I've looked up include [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892492/sharing-typescript-code-between-two-projects-in-a-monorepo-with-yarn-2-workspace) about sharing common code and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737470/fix-wrong-auto-imports-in-typescript-monorepo) that uses `paths` to solve it. Nothing has worked so far for me.

root package.json

```
"workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "backend/*",
    "packages/*"
]
```

The folder structure is as follows.

```
|
|__ apps
|  |__react-native-app
|  |__react-app
|  |__next-app
|__ backend
|  |__express-app
|__ packages
   |__ shared-types
```

Comment: Doing that defeats the purpose of having shared code. If I have to individually go into each project and update the declarations each time I add thing to shared code base then I think it will be same as just writing the code in the project itself.

Comment: If the issue is with typescript and on the react projeto works, but react native don't, I guess the problem is in your tsconfig file. Did you take a look on that? Have you tried changing the react native's tsconfig to be the same as the react one? If you have done all of that, could you share both tsconfig files?

Comment: Yes I actually tried a bunch of options, I think setting up `paths` was the one that made the most sense but the auto imports just won't work even for that.

Comment: I have mentioned the questions that I found somewhat relevant in case I missed something in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week of constant scratching of the head, I found the solution to this problem by looking at the default `tsconfig.json` created by `tsc --init`.

All I needed to do was add the following flags and it started working. The updated `tsconfig.json` looks like this

```
{
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true
}
```

Comment: "declaration": true, worked for me